# Existence of holomorphic function on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f:D\to D$ where  $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1\}$ such that $f(1/2)=-1/2$ and $f'(1/4)=1$?

I tried with [Schwarz pick lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Schwarz-PickLemma.html), but for that I need the value of $f(1/4)$ which is not given. So kindly tell me ow to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there other conditions?  We can certainly exhibit a real polynomial such that $f(1/2) = -1/2$ and $f'(1/4) = 1$.  This would be holomorphic, not only on the unit disc, but on the "entire" complex plane.

Comment: I edited my question. It is a function from $D$ to $D$.